# usermodehelper API calls in watchdog_fire

Tags: c, linux, kernel

Can I call usermodehelper APIs in software irq?

For example, I would like to execute "pstack" program in user space when kernel is executing `watchdog_fire()`. I've tried to call it but it's always causing some crash in the kernel.

```
watchdog_fire+0xf4/0x138
run_timer_softirq+0x168/0x248
_do_softirq+0x114/0x158
do_softirq+0x68/0x70
plat_irq_dispatch+0xc0/0x180
ret_from_irq+0x0/0x4
```

Comment: Wait, what? You're trying to _execute a program_ from inside a _kernel interrupt_!? No, you can't do that.

Comment: Then can I execute a program after creating work_queue in the watchdog_fire?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this comment in the linux 3.4.4 kernel tree (kernel/kmod.c). This may or may not have changed in more recent kernel versions. Note the `wait` flag.

```
/**
 * call_usermodehelper_exec - start a usermode application
 * @sub_info: information about the subprocessa
 * @wait: wait for the application to finish and return status.
 *        when -1 don't wait at all, but you get no useful error back when
 *        the program couldn't be exec'ed. This makes it safe to call
 *        from interrupt context.
 *
 * Runs a user-space application.  The application is started
 * asynchronously if wait is not set, and runs as a child of keventd.
 * (ie. it runs with full root capabilities).
 */
int call_usermodehelper_exec(struct subprocess_info *sub_info, int wait)
```